# Delphi 2010 Changing class names when importing type library?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to use delphi to create a database so I'm going to import the "Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security" to connect to an access db but I can't edit the class names before it is imported like you could do in delphi 7 e.g. changing "TTable" to "TADOXTable". As the box to change class names is greyed out.

Is there a way to change this or do I have to manual edit the class name in the ADOX_TBL.pas file generated?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this instead of just using Delphi's TAdoxxx components (TAdoDataSet, TAdoQuery, etc)?  They are based on importing the COM objects from the MDac ADO layer, but with a lot of extra coding so as to work as descendants of Delphi's TDataset.  They can use Access, MS Sql Server and a variety of other back-end databases.

Comment: @MartynA Well to be honest this is my first time trying to create and manage a db from a delphi program and the guide I was following showed it being done this way. This is what I was trying to follow http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa072401a.htm

Comment: Delphi About.com has an awful lot of poor content

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How would you go about creating an access database through delphi. I've only been able to find articles about connecting to an already created one.

Comment: That's a totally different question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well obviously, if my first method was poor it's the the one I'm going to keep trying.

Comment: Sure. But you can't ask a new question in a comment. You would need to ask a new question. Ask directly about the problem, and not your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the short answers to "Is there a way to change this or do I have to manual edit the class name in the ADOX_TBL.pas file generated?" seem to be "No" and "Yes", respectively, at least for D2010 and e.g. CB2007.

I think that at some point they re-worked the Component Install wizard and the ability to edit the CoClass names went awol for a few versions.  I don't know for sure, but this may have been related to the work they evidently had to do to allow for importing Net assemblies.

Fortunately, it's not a show-stopper because as you say you can edit the names in the TLB import .Pas file, and then add it to the "Contains" clause of a new or existing Package .Dpk file.

That could get tedious though if you have to repeatedly re-import that same type library.  In that case you might take a look at the file `TLibImp.Sym` in your Delphi Bin directory.  Amongst other things, it contains equate-style mappings for a number of COM libraries (to make more sensible names for some and avoid name collisions between others).  It's not documented but it should be fairly obvious how to add your own entries to it.

By XE4 the ability to edit the CoClass names had been reinstated as shown below:

[image]

Clicking the [...] button to the right of the Class Name(s) list brings up this pop-up

[image]

where you can edit the class names for the components the wizard will create in the TLB import unit, just like you could in D7.

Comment: It seems like that must be an improvement as the 2010 version of that menu looks like ![this.](http://imgur.com/YjNhabB)

Comment: The expression "Ah!" springs to mind.  I may still have a copy of D2010 installed somewhere, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: I assume there must be a way to do it, I couldn't see why you would remove the feature.

Comment: Did this answer your question, even though it wasn't the answer you were hoping for?